# Why are not ruby threads working as expected?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

In this code

```
threads=[]
for index in 1...100
  threads<<Thread.new {puts index}
end
for thread in threads
  thread.join
end
```

I expect all numbers between 1 and 99 to be printed, but when I run it, the output prints out mostly as "99" with a few 3s in between (http://paste.ubuntu.com/15189462/).

Why is ruby acting like this?

Comment: Im not a ruby coder, but I would expect the "index" to be captured in a closure, and thus, all threads have access to the same index.
doing something like:  `tmp=index` and then `puts tmp` would solve that if my thoughts are correct

Comment: I just realized that myself

Comment: @RogerAlsing Thanks for the answer, I was looking at it as a function call, not a piece of code being passed to thread.